# invalid context 0x0 within custom UIView - follow-up question

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass

This post:
[invalid context 0x0 within custom UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644739/invalid-context-0x0-within-custom-uiview)
...should have given me the key to solve my problem, but I could not avoid the invalid context error. Some clarification would be much appreciated.

I want to draw lines in a subview presented when the ViewController loads. To do that, I create a subclass to UIView, which is similar to SplitCircleView posted by StartPlayer.

To run the code, create a new project and replace the contents of the ViewController file with:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let mySubViewInstance = SplitCircleView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //let mySubViewInstance = SplitCircleView()
        mySubViewInstance.setNeedsDisplay(mySubViewInstance.frame)
    }
}

class SplitCircleView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //self.setNeedsDisplay()
        //draw(frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //self.setNeedsDisplay()
        //draw(frame)
    }

    override func setNeedsDisplay(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 87.5, endPercent: 37.5, color: .green)
        drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 37.5, endPercent: 87.5, color: .red)
    }

    func drawSlice(rect: CGRect, startPercent: CGFloat, endPercent: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.width / 2, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height / 2)
        let radius = (min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2)
        let startAngle = startPercent / 100 * .pi * 2 - .pi
        let endAngle = endPercent / 100 * .pi * 2 - .pi
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: center)
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

How can I avoid the invalid context error and draw something in the subview when the ViewController loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places to fix.

You are creating a new view , so you need to add to the view of your viewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mySubViewInstance = SplitCircleView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(mySubViewInstance)

  //  mySubViewInstance.setNeedsDisplay(mySubViewInstance.frame)
}
```

second is to draw function not using setNeedsDisplay();

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

       self.backgroundColor = .clear
    drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 87.5, endPercent: 37.5, color: .green)
    drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 37.5, endPercent: 87.5, color: .red)
}
```

Thus, you will get your beautiful drawing here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. @rmadddy thank you too for the correction of the draw() call. Helps a lot, but I still have an issue if I want to specify the dimensions of the view from viewDidLoad(). In that case SplitCircleView is initiated with the custom dimensions, but draw() is not called. When draw() is called following the .addSubview command the input argument reverts back to the dimensions of the superview. How can I combine the initialisation of SplitCircleView and the function call?

Comment: This is an simple version.  you may consider put the splitcircleview into IB. and then you can use autolayout to add constraints. let mySubViewInstance = SplitCircleView() should change to @IBOutlet var mySubViewInstance : SplitCircleView!. Then link it to a UIView Object. Now we initialize it with  let mySubViewInstance = SplitCircleView.init(frame: self.view.bounds). When you are using IB, it will initialize with the second init : i.e.  init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder). You don't need it, but just let you know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You should be overriding `draw`, not `setNeedsDisplay`.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear

    drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 87.5, endPercent: 37.5, color: .green)
    drawSlice(rect: rect, startPercent: 37.5, endPercent: 87.5, color: .red)
}
```

And the setting of the background color only needs to be done once so `draw` is not really the ideal place for that line. Move it to the `init`.

`setNeedsDisplay` is an indication that drawing needs to be updated. But it is `draw` that does the actual drawing.